# rspec fails saying expected: 15.35, got: 15.35 using ==, this doesn't make sense to me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, floating-point

My rspec is failing, but both the expected and got values are identical.

It shows:

```
expected: 15.35
     got: 15.35  (using ==)
```

Is this a datatype issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this is probably just a float comparison issue.  I think that the common solution is as suggested here: http://blog.daveastels.com/files/QuickRef.pdf

```
# Floating Point Comparison
object.should be_close <val>, <delta>
object.should_not be_close <val>, <delta>
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined method 'should_be_close'

Comment: object.should be_close(<val>, <delta>) - http://rdoc.info/gems/rspec/1.3.2/Spec/Matchers#be_close-instance_method